# Invalid left join on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I´m trying to excecute a simple left join on SQL Server but it keeps getting me the same message.

```
Select * from customers left join orders on customers.id = orders.customer_id group by customers.id order by amount;
```

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 39 Column 'customers.first_name' is
> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
> aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I´m not sure what else to do.
If it helps, here there are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customers(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(100), last_name VARCHAR(100), email VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE orders(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, order_date DATE, amount DECIMAL(8,2), customer_id INT, FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id));
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results.  If you're grouping by `customers.id` you need that in the select list as well as an aggregate.  What is it that you're looking for in the results?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clause has to include all columns in the `SELECT` clause that are not selected via aggregate functions (e.g. `MAX`, `MIN`, `COUNT`). Try using something other than `SELECT *`

Comment: I must say, the error message seems to be pretty clear, what about it are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Simply search for "first in group". It has nothing to do with any join and is just a matter of misunderstanding how the GROUP BY clause works.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create an aggregate using `GROUP BY`, you can only `SELECT` what you have grouped by and the aggregate functions (e.g., `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc.). For your query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN orders on customers.id = orders.customer_id 
GROUP BY customers.id 
ORDER BY amount;
```

Since you `GROUP BY customers.id`, the only things that can appear in your `SELECT` list is `customers.id` and aggregate functions. You are getting the error because the `*` means all columns, but you are only allowed to use `customers.id` and the aggregate function. For example, this would work:

```sql
SELECT customers.id 
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN orders on customers.id = orders.customer_id 
GROUP BY customers.id 
ORDER BY amount;
```

As far as what you want to see, I cannot tell from this query. If you wanted to see the smallest order for each customer id, you could do that with:

```sql
SELECT customers.id, MIN(orders.amount) AS [SmallestOrder] 
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN orders on customers.id = orders.customer_id 
GROUP BY customers.id 
ORDER BY amount;
```

So the cause of the error is hopefully clear now, but what data you want to find isn't.